# Can one receive a Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) message in a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write an application where most of the logic sits in a Google Apps Script attached to a Google Sheet. I need some clients to periodically send a message to this script/sheet. Is this possible? I know I'd be able to send messages from the Sheets Script to the clients using an HTTP request, but I need the Sheets script to receive messages too.

Comment: sheets don't support onGet/onPost afaik @ZigMandel

Comment: you can make it so when the message is sent, the doGet is called on the apps script.

Answer (score 0):

No. it currently supports 3 platforms (Android, iOS and Chrome)

It is stated in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)